# How to view each commit in magit easily?

Tags: magit

When I press <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> in Magit's status buffer, then it shows a log buffer listing commits. Then I want to show details about the commit at point in another window, but at the same time I want to stay in the log buffer/window. If I press <kbd>RET</kbd>, then it shows another buffer with details about the commit, but it also jumps into the new buffer. How to keep the log buffer selected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>SPC</kbd> calls `magit-diff-show-or-scroll-up`

Answer (score 8):

Instead of <kbd>RET</kbd> use <kbd>SPC</kbd>.

The first time you do that it will show the commit in a new buffer and display that buffer in another window, but it does not select that window/buffer.

Pressing <kbd>SPC</kbd> again will scroll in the window which displays the commit buffer, so you don't even have to go to that buffer if some of its content is initially hidden because the window is to small.

Comment: I am using spacemacs, the newest version. SPC + SPC will pop up a window to select all possible functions.

Comment: it works now. Just use the answer from phils

Comment: how about binding `(magit-diff-show-or-scroll-up)` to UP and DOWN keys